# Convert 3d 4x4 Rotation Matrix into 2d

Tags: 3d, matrix, 2d, collada

Say we have a 4x4 matrix with indices like so:

```
00 01 02 03
10 11 12 13
20 21 22 23
30 31 32 33
```

How does one convert the rotation data (ignoring the z axis, if that helps) contained in this matrix into a single 2d rotational angle (in radians)?

Background: I have a 3D .dae animation exported from Blender into the Collada format. The animation is technically 2d, all of the z axis values are 0. I'm trying to convert the 4x4 matrices into 2d translation, rotation and scale data.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Scale matrix `S` looks like this:

```
sx 0  0  0
0  sy 0  0
0  0  sz 0
0  0  0  1
```

Translation matrix `T` looks like this:

```
1  0  0  0
0  1  0  0
0  0  1  0
tx ty tz 1
```

Z-axis rotation matrix `R`looks like this:

```
 cos(a) sin(a)  0  0
-sin(a) cos(a)  0  0
   0      0     1  0
   0      0     0  1
```

If you have a transformation matrix `M`, it is a result of a number of multiplications of `R`, `T` and `S` matrices. Looking at `M`, the order and number of those multiplications is unknown. However, if we assume that `M=S*R*T` we can decompose it into separate matrices. Firstly let's calculate `S*R*T`:

```
        ( sx*cos(a) sx*sin(a) 0  0)       (m11 m12 m13 m14)
S*R*T = (-sy*sin(a) sy*cos(a) 0  0) = M = (m21 m22 m23 m24)
        (     0         0     sz 0)       (m31 m32 m33 m34)
        (     tx        ty    tz 1)       (m41 m42 m43 m44)
```

Since we know it's a 2D transformation, getting translation is straightforward:

```
translation = vector2D(tx, ty) = vector2D(m41, m42)
```

To calculate rotation and scale, we can use `sin(a)^2+cos(a)^2=1`:

```
(m11 / sx)^2 + (m12 / sx)^2 = 1
(m21 / sy)^2 + (m22 / sy)^2 = 1

m11^2 + m12^2 = sx^2
m21^2 + m22^2 = sy^2

sx = sqrt(m11^2 + m12^2)
sy = sqrt(m21^2 + m22^2)

scale = vector2D(sx, sy)

rotation_angle = atan2(sx*m22, sy*m12)
```

Comment: The only thing I would add it not avoid `acos` as it disregards the sign of rotation. It is better to use `a=atan2(sx*m22,sy*m12)` or `a=atan2(-sy*m11,sx*m21)`. {I use `atan2(dx,dy)`, but some systems define it as `atan2(dy,dx)` so be careful}.

Comment: @ja72: Thank you, I fixed it. It's also convenient to assume that scale is positive while calculating the angle.

Answer (score 2):

[this library](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/code/transformations.py.html) has routines for converting a 4x4 matrix into its 5 components - rotation, translation, scale, shear, and perspective. You should be able to take the formulas and just drop the 3rd component of the 3d vectors.

Comment: calculating eigenvalue is really a smart method.

Comment: Pros: Looks promising. Cons: Dependent on NumPy, hence, it seems a bit convoluted. Anything similar written in C++?

Comment: The algorithm and an implementation in C are published in (1) Decomposing a matrix into simple transformations. Spencer Thomas. In "Graphics Gems II", pp 320-323. Morgan Kaufmann, 1991. 
See also (2) Recovering the data from the transformation matrix. Ronald Goldman. In "Graphics Gems II", pp 324-331. Morgan Kaufmann, 1991.

Comment: I don't know of anything in c/c++