# What are the maths behind 3D billboard sprites? (was: 3D transformation matrix to 2D matrix)

Tags: graphics, matrix, 3d, transformation

I have a 3D point in space. The point's exact orientation/position is expressed through a **4x4 transformation matrix.**

I want to draw a [billboard (3D Sprite)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprite_%28computer_graphics%29#Application) to this point. **I know the projected position** (i.e. 3D->2D) of the point; the billboard is facing the camera so that's very helpful too. ***What I don't know is the scaling that the billboard should have!***

To make things more complex, the **4x4 matrix** may have all sorts of transformations: 3D rotation, 3D scaling, 3D transposition. Assume that the camera is as simple as it can be: position at (0,0,0), no rotation.

So, can I "extract" the scaling of the billboard sprite from this 4x4 matrix?

### -

### ***WAS:***

I have a 3D affine transformation 4x4 matrix. I need to convert it (project) to a 2D affine transformation 3x3 matrix, which looks like this:

[image]

3D rotations are irrelevant and if present may be discarded; I am only interested in translation and most importantly scaling.

Can anyone help with the equations for each of the <s>six</s> **4** values? (lets say **t<sub>x</sub>, t<sub>y</sub>** are also known)

**Additional info:**

The Matrix3D is the global transformation of a 3D point, say (0,0,0). Its purpose is to be projected on a 2D plane (the computer screen).

I know how to project a 3D point to 2D space, what I am looking for is to preserve additional transformation information beyond position, i.e. **scaling**: as you may know, the **scaling** property is also altered when projecting the point on a 2D plane.

I also forgot to mention that the **perspective projection** properties are also known, i.e.:

```
field of view (single value)
focal length (single value)
projection center (viewpoint position - 2D value)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you not using spherical coordinate system then this task is not solvable because discarding Z-coordinate before projection will remove the distance form the projection point and therefore you do not know how to apply perspective.

You have two choices (unless I overlooked something):

1. **apply 3D transform matrix**

   and then use only x,y - coordinates of the result
2. **create 3x3 transformation matrix for rotation/projection**

   and add offset vector before or after applying it. Be aware that this approach do not use homogenous coordinates !!!

**[Edit1] equations for clarity**

[image: 3x3 vs. 4x4 transform matrix]

Do not forget that `3x3` matrix + vector transforms are not cumulative !!! That is the reason why `4x4` transforms are used instead. Now you can throw away the last row of matrix/vector `(Xz,Yz,Zz), (z0)` and then the output vector is just `(x', y')`. Of course after this you cannot use the inverse transform because you lost Z coordinate.

**Scaling is done by changing the size of axis direction vectors**

Btw. if your projection plane is also `XY`-plane without rotations then:

```
x' = (x-x0)*d/(z-z0)
y' = (y-y0)*d/(z-z0)
```

`(x,y,z)` - point to project

`(x',y')` - projected point

`(x0,y0,z0)` - projection origin

`d` - focal length

**[Edit2] well after question edit the meaning is completely different**

I assume you want sprite always facing camera. It is ugly but simplifies things like grass,trees,...

`M` - your matrix

`P` - projection matrix inside `M`

 If you have origin of `M = (0,0,0)` without rotations/scaling/skew then `M=P`

`pnt` - point of your billboard (center I assume) (`w=1`) `[GCS]`

`dx,dy` - half sizes of billboard `[LCS]`

`A,B,C,D` - projected edges of your billboard `[GCS]`

`[GCS]` - global coordinate system

`[LCS]` - local coordinate system

1. **if you know the projection matrix**

   I assume it is glFrustrum or gluPerspective ...  then:

   ```
   (x,y,z,w)=(M*(P^-1))*pnt  // transformed center of billboard without projection
   A=P*(x-dx,y-dy,z,w)
   B=P*(x-dx,y+dy,z,w)
   C=P*(x+dx,y+dy,z,w)
   D=P*(x+dx,y-dy,z,w)
   ```
2. **If your `M` matrix is too complex for #1 to work**

   ```
   MM=(M*(P^-1))     // transform matrix without projection
   XX=MM(Xx,Xy,Xz)   // X - axis vector from MM [GCS](look at the image above on the right for positions inside matrix)
   YY=MM(Yx,Yy,Yz)   // Y - axis vector from MM [GCS]
   X =(M^-1)*XX*dx   // X - axis vector from MM [LCS] scaled to dx
   Y =(M^-1)*YY*dy   // Y - axis vector from MM [LCS] scaled to dy
   A = M*(pnt-X-Y)
   B = M*(pnt-X+Y)
   C = M*(pnt+X+Y)
   D = M*(pnt+X-Y)
   ```

**[Edit3] scalling only**

```
MM=(M*(P^-1))      // transform matrix without projection
sx=|MM(Xx,Xy,Xz)|  // size of X - axis vector from MM [GCS] = scale x
sy=|MM(Yx,Yy,Yz)|  // size of Y - axis vector from MM [GCS] = scale y
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little on (2)? I don't want to discard Z, I just want to project SCALING alongside X,Y coords

Comment: That's a greatly extensive answer... but AFAICS, you have given me the equations for getting the projected point. As I originally said, I know how to get the projected point. I am re-editing the whole question because I think I have caused confusion.

Comment: Thank you Spektre! But I feel that you will flame me for this: You have given me the 4 edges of the billboard, though I am not using OpenGL but Flash. In order to render my billboard correctly, I need to pass 2 things: the projected point (I have this already) and SCALING factors (scaleX & scaleY). From your math, I suppose a way to calculate the scaling is this: scaleX=(D-A)/(billboard_original_sizeX) . But is there a "shortcut" to your math so that I get the SCALING without calculating all four edges of the billboard? Sorry for keeping bothering you!!!

Comment: @Bill Kotsias I think edit3 is what you seek (if I understand the scaling factor of your render correctly)

Comment: Great, I'll check it out and get back to you with the results (before the bounty expires of course!)

Answer (score 1):

Scale matrix `S` looks like this:

```
sx 0  0  0
0  sy 0  0
0  0  sz 0
0  0  0  1
```

Translation matrix `T` looks like this:

```
1  0  0  0
0  1  0  0
0  0  1  0
tx ty tz 1
```

Z-axis rotation matrix `R`looks like this:

```
 cos(a) sin(a)  0  0
-sin(a) cos(a)  0  0
   0      0     1  0
   0      0     0  1
```

If you have a transformation matrix `M`, it is a result of a number of multiplications of `R`, `T` and `S` matrices. Looking at `M`, the order and number of those multiplications is unknown. However, if we assume that `M=S*R*T` we can decompose it into separate matrices. Firstly let's calculate `S*R*T`:

```
        ( sx*cos(a) sx*sin(a) 0  0)       (m11 m12 m13 m14)
S*R*T = (-sy*sin(a) sy*cos(a) 0  0) = M = (m21 m22 m23 m24)
        (     0         0     sz 0)       (m31 m32 m33 m34)
        (     tx        ty    tz 1)       (m41 m42 m43 m44)
```

Since we know it's a 2D transformation, getting translation is straightforward:

```
translation = vector2D(tx, ty) = vector2D(m41, m42)
```

To calculate rotation and scale, we can use `sin(a)^2+cos(a)^2=1`:

```
(m11 / sx)^2 + (m12 / sx)^2 = 1
(m21 / sy)^2 + (m22 / sy)^2 = 1

m11^2 + m12^2 = sx^2
m21^2 + m22^2 = sy^2

sx = sqrt(m11^2 + m12^2)
sy = sqrt(m21^2 + m22^2)

scale = vector2D(sx, sy)

rotation_angle = atan2(sx*m22, sy*m12)
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10629737/convert-3d-4x4-rotation-matrix-into-2d)

Hope this help you

Comment: Very helpful indeed, but not the answer to my question. I have re-edited the question in hope that I'll get the correct answer...