# Representing Points on a Circular Radar Math approach

Tags: javascript, google-maps, math, maps

I am coding a simple app that can show you what friends are around you, but not in the normal map but on a really circular radar like UI:

[image: [Imgur]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Au3IP.png)

Like this, where i have every users latitude, longitude, and of course my own being the center.

I also measure the distance of every user to position them so the data I know is their lat, longitude and distance to me.

For mathematical reasons let's say the radar is 100 pixels radius, I can distance them by the distance from me using the left or right positioning, but in terms of top or bottom it gets a litte trickier, since i try to convert their latitude - my latitude into a percentual result and then put them on the radar... but I think there are maybe better ways with polar to cartesian coordinates, but im really kinda clueless.

Is there a best approach with these types of interfaces or anything implemented around there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. **convert long,lat of all points to cartesian 3D space coordinates**

   it is conversion spherical -> cartesian 3D space. Math behind is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system). After this all points `(long,lat,alt)` will became `(x,y,z)` where `(0,0,0)` is center of the **Earth**

   - `X` axis is `lat=0,long=0 [rad]`
   - `Y` axis is `lat=0,long=+PI/2 [rad]`
   - `Z` axis is North
   - `XY` plane is equator

   [image: globe]

   If you want more precision handle **Earth** as ellipsoid instead of sphere

   ```
   long = <     0 , +2*PI > [rad]
   lat  = < -PI/2 , +PI/2 > [rad]
   alt  = altitude above sea level [m]
   Re =6378141.4; [m]
   Rp =6356755.0; [m]

   R=alt+sqrt( (Re*cos(lat))^2 + (Rp*sin(lat))^2 )
   x=R*cos(lat)*cos(long)
   y=R*cos(lat)*sin(long)
   z=R*sin(lat)
   ```
2. **create RADAR local cartesian coordinate system**

   [image: NEH]

   Basically you need to obtain 3D vectors for `X,Y,Z` axises. They must be perpendicular to each other and pointing to the right direction from **RADAR** origin point `(P0)`.

   You can use vector multiplication for that because it creates perpendicular vector to its multiplicants. Direction is dependent on the order of multiplicants so experiment a little.

   ```
   //altitude this one is easy
   Z = P0
   //north (chose one that is non zero, resp. bigger to avoid accuracy problems)
   X = (1,0,0) x Z // old X axis * Altitude
   X = (0,1,0) x Z // old Y axis * Altitude
   //east is now also easy
   Y = X x Z 
   // now normalize all of them to unit vectors
   X = X / |X|
   Y = Y / |Y|
   Z = Z / |Z|
   // and check if they are not negative (X,Y)
   // if they are then swap multiplicants or multiply by -1
   // do not forget that X is computed by two methods so swap the correct one
   ```

   - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21100338/2521214) is math behind constructing an 4x4 transform matrix
   - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21611264/2521214) you can see on an image difference between homogenous 4x4 and direct 3x3 3D transform matrices and math
3. **convert all points to RADAR coordinate system**

   just multiply all points by **RADAR** transform matrix `M`

   ```
   Q(i) = P(i)*M
   ```

   so the points `Q(i)` are now local to **RADAR**

   - `(0,0,0)` means radar origin (center)
   - `(1,0,0)` points to north
   - `(0,1,0)` points to east
   - `(0,0,1)` points up

   so now just multiply all cordinates by **RADAR** scale

   ```
   scale = RADAR_radius/RADAR_range;
   ```

   - `RADAR_radius` is size of you **RADAR** on screen  in pixels or units of coordinates
   - `RADAR_range` is the max distance the **RADAR** biggest circle represents [m]

   after this just draw the dot to **RADAR** (swap `x,y` because I use `X` as North not `Y`) and also you can discard all points that are more distant then range. Also you can add 3D **RADAR** like in old Elite by adding `Z` coordinate to vertical axis (or draw an L line)

   [image: 3D RADAR]

Hope it helps a little and was not too much confusing...

Comment: WOW, thank you for the thoughtful explanation.

This is really amazing, i wish I could give you more than one upvote... but i'll share it with my friends so they can give it to you.