# Normalising angled Earth magnetic field

Tags: python, 3d, raspberry-pi, physics, wgs84

Me and my team are participating in ESA [Astro Pi](https://astro-pi.org/) challenge. Our program will ran on the ISS for 3 hours and we will our results back and analyze them.

---

We want to investigate the connection between the magnetic intensity measurements from [Sense HAT](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/sense-hat/) magnetometer and predictions from the World Magnetic Model (WMM). We want to research the accuracy of the magnetometer on Sense HAT.

The program will get raw magnetometer data (`X`, `Y` and `Z`) in microteslas from Sense HAT and calculate values H and F as described in [British geological survey's article](https://geomag.bgs.ac.uk/education/earthmag.html) (section 2.1). It will then save them to CSV file, along with timestamp and location calculated with ephem.

We will then compare values Z, H and F from ISS and WMM and create maps with our data and differences (like figures 6, 8 and 10). We will then research, how accurate are Sense HAT magnetometer data.

---

We want to compare our data with data from WMM to see how accurate is Sense HAT magnetometer, but we have a problem that orientation of magnetometer will always be different. Because of that, our data will always be (very) different from WMM so we won't be able to compare them correctly.

We talked with Astro Pi support team and they suggested to "normalise the angled measurements so it looks like they were taken by a device aligned North/South".

Unfortunately, we (and they) don't know how to do this, so they suggested to ask this question on Stack Exchange. I asked it on [Math Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3075957/normalising-angled-earth-magnetic-field), [Physics Stack Exchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/454899/normalising-angled-earth-magnetic-field) and [Raspberry Pi Forums](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=104&t=231936). Unforcenetly, they didn't received any answers, so I am asking this question again.

How can we do this? We have data for timestamp, ISS location (latitude, longitude, elevation), magnetic data (`X`, `Y` and `Z`) and also direction from the North.

We want to normalise our data so we will be able to correctly compare them with data from WMM.

---

Here is part of our program that calculates magnetometer values (which gets not normalised data):

```
compass = sense.get_compass_raw()

try:
    # Get raw data (values are swapped because Sense HAT on ISS is in different position)
    # x: northerly intensity
    # y: easterly intensity
    #  z: vertical intensity
    x = float(compass['z'])
    y = float(compass['y'])
    z = float(compass['x'])

except (ValueError, KeyError) as err:
    # Write error to log (excluded from this snippet)
    pass

try:
    # h: horizontal intensity
    # f: total intensity
    # d: declination
    # i: inclination
    h = sqrt(x ** 2 + y ** 2)
    f = sqrt(h ** 2 + z ** 2)
    d = degrees(atan(y / x))
    i = degrees(atan(z / h))

except (TypeError, ValueError, ZeroDivisionError) as err:
    # Write error to log (excluded from this snippet)
    pass
```

There is also some simple simulator available with our code: https://trinket.io/library/trinkets/cc87813ce7

---

Part of email from Astro Pi team about location and position of magnetometer:

> - Z is going down through the middle of the Sense Hat.
> - X runs between the USB ports and SD card slot.
> - Y runs across from the HDMI port to the 40 way pin header.
>
> On the ISS the AstroPi orientation is that the Ethernet + USB ports face the deck and the SD card slot is towards the sky.
>   So, that's basically a rotation around the Y axis from flat. So you keep the Y axis the same and swap around Z and X.
>
> ---
>
> It can help to look at the Google Street view of the interior of the ISS Columbus module to get a better idea how the AstroPi is positioned;
>   https://www.google.com/streetview/#international-space-station/columbus-research-laboratory
>
> If you pan the camera down and to the right, you'll see a green light - that's the AstroPi. The direction of travel for the whole space station is towards the inflatable Earth ball you can see on the left.
>
> [image: ISS]
>
> So, broadly speaking, the SD card slot points towards azimuth as in away from the centre of the Earth (so the X axis).
>   The LED matrix is facing the direction of travel of the space station (the Z axis).
>
> Because of the orbital path of the ISS the Z and Y axes will continually change direction relative to the poles as it moves around the Earth.
>
> [image: location]
>
> So, I am guessing you want to normalise the angled measurements so it looks like they were taken by a device aligned North/South?

Comment: Can you specify on the meaning of "direction from the North"? Does this mean the vector from the north pole to the satellite?

Comment: @Saviour From Sense HAT reference: "Calls set_imu_config to disable the gyroscope and accelerometer then gets the direction of North from the magnetometer in degrees."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to create local reference coordinate system similar to **NEH** (north,east,height/altitude/up) something like

- [Representing Points on a Circular Radar Math approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24404784/2521214).

Its commonly used in aviation as a reference frame (heading is derived from it) so your reference frame is computed from your geo location and its axises pointing to **North, East** and **Up**.

Now the problem is what does it mean `aligned North/South` and `normalizing`.. ?

If reference device measure just **projection** than you would need to do something like this:

```
dot(measured_vector,reference_unit_direction)
```

where the direction would be the `North` direction but as unit vector.

If the reference device measure a **full 3D** too then you need to transform both reference and tested measured data into the same coordinate system. That is done by using

- [transform matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214)

So simple `matrix * vector` multiplication will do ... Only then compute the values `H,F,Z` which I do not know what they are and too lazy to go through papers ... would expect `E,H` or `B` vectors instead.

However if you do not have the geo location at moment of measure then you have just the `North` direction in respect to the ISS in form of Euler angles so you can not construct 3D reference frame at all (unless you got 2 known vectors instead of just one like UP). In such case you need to go with the option 1 **projection** (using dot product and north direction vector). So you will handle just scalar values instead of 3D vectors afterwards.

**[Edit1]**

From the link of yours:

> The geomagnetic field vector, B, is described by the orthogonal
>   components X (northerly intensity), Y (easterly intensity) and Z
>   (vertical intensity, positive downwards);

This is not my field of expertise so I might be wrong here but this is how I understand it:

`B(Bx,By,Bz)` - magnetic field vector

`a(ax,ay,az)` - acceleration

Now `F` is a magnitude of `B` so its invariant on rotation:

```
F = |B| = sqrt( Bx*Bx + By*By + Bz*Bz )
```

you need to compute the X,Y,Z values of B in the NED reference frame (North,East,Down) so you need the basis vectors first:

```cpp
Down = a/|a|  // gravity points down
North = B/|B| // north is close to B direction
East = cross(Down,North) // East is perpendicular to Down and North
North = cross(East,Down) // north is perpendicular to Down and East, this should convert North to the horizontal plane
```

You should render them to visually check if they point to correct directions if not negate them by reordering the cross operands (I might have the order wrong I am used to use Up vector instead). Now just convert `B` to **NED** :

```
X = dot(North,B)
Y = dot(East,B)
Z = dot(Down,B)
```

And now you can compute the `H`

```
H = sqrt( X*X +Y*Y )
```

The vector math needed for this you will find in the transform matrix link above.

beware this will work only if no accelerations are present (the sensor is not on a robotic arm during its operation, or ISS is not doing a burn...) Otherwise you need to obtain the **NED** frame differently (like from onboard systems)

If this not work correctly then you can compute NED from your ISS position but for that you would need to know the exact orientation and displacement of the sensor in respect to your simulation model that provide your location. I do not know what rotations ISS do so I would not touch that subject unless as a last resort.

I am afraid that I will not have time for coding for some time ... anyway coding without sample input data nor the coordinate system expalnations and all the input/output variables is insanity ... simple negation of axis will invalidate the whole thing and there is a lot of duplicities along the ways and to cover all of them you would end up with many many versions to try to...

Apps should be build up incrementally but I am afraid that without the access to simulation or real HW that is not possible. And there is a whole bunch of things that could go wrong ... making even simple programs a magnitude harder to code... I would first check the `F` as it does not require any "normalization" first to see if the results are off or not. If off it might suggest different units or god knows what ...

Comment: This is data sheet of IMU sensor which has magnetometer: http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/DM00103319.pdf

Comment: Values X and Y and calculated values of magnetometer will depend of direction of Sense HAT. I don't want that because I won't be able to compare them with data from World Magnetic Model. I want to "normalise" (I don't know if this is correct term) so I would be able to compare them with data from WMM. I want to get differences with data from Sense HAT and WMM.

Comment: Also, can you also provide some details and Python code for that? Thanks!

Comment: @FilipŠ 1. coding without any specs is meaningless we do not know what coordinate systems, knowns and unknowns  you got  the datasheet you provided is a 3 axis sensor so you got 3D data as I assumed but the question is do you know how it is oriented in respect to earth/ISS/equator? And even bigger question is what is the form of data you want to reference with  is it scalar/2D/3D in what coordinate system in respect to what? If the reference is your magnetic field model of Earth then you also need the geo location.  2. I code mostly in C++ python is gibberish to me.

Comment: @FilipŠ the orientation can be partialy obtained from the accelerometers providing you with approximate up/down vector in respect to your sensor but only approximate as there are a lot of things going on not just gravity and i assume the sensor is not fixed but on some arm mechanism or something ...  the magnetic sensor might provide you with approximate North/South direction vector so from these you might construct local NEH matrix ... if you know the position of ISS but can you do the same for the refference data too?

Comment: @FilipŠ I think there should be some onboard system doing this based on known starts (tracking) or even tapping to GPS like positioning I do not know as I do not develop in this field and do not have enough background info. The position might be also only virtual not measured computed from actual time and orbital parameters of the ISS

Comment: Direction of North is not needed for our research. I just included it if it is needed for that normalisation.

Comment: Our real data would be `x,`, `y` and `z` (the magnetic intensity of the axis in microteslas (µT)) from magnetometer. We would then calculate `h` and `f` from them. We would then also get data from WMM and compare them with our data to get diffreances, but we would need to normalise them before that.

Comment: For coordinate system, we use classic latitude, longitude and elevation calculated with Python module `ephem`. So, if I correctly understand you, we would need to transform them into NEH.

Comment: Also, you could also add C++ example. The code needs to be written in Python, but I also understand C++ so I would be able to convert it.

Comment: Thank you!

For the coordinate system, we use data from ephem `sublat` and `sublong`. Here is reference for this: https://rhodesmill.org/pyephem/quick.html#body-compute-date. You should look to section artificial satellites. I don't know what exact coordinate system it uses.

There is also some simple simulator available with our code: https://trinket.io/library/trinkets/cc87813ce7

Comment: @FilipŠ having the location is not enough if you are simulating ,... you need to know exactly how the sensor is oriented in respect to ISS ... and accomodate that into the basis vectors.  You should add the simulation link into your question too. I am still not fully convinced of the north vector computation from `B` theoretically it should work but ... I think horizontal plane is OK but not sure about the heading ... so X,Y might be rotated, but that should not affect the `H` computation

Comment: I have information how is sensor oriented. I am currently on phone so I will update my question with this details later today.

Comment: I added more details in question.

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive answer. I asked Astro Pi team again to be sure if it is completely correct. When I receive an answer from them, I will test and accept this. Also, if I correctly understand your answer (in Edit1), I would also need acceleration for calculation? This is OK because it is available, but I need to know because I need to manually get it.

Comment: @FilipŠ You need the acceleration for computing the down vector so if you got it available in known reference frame from a different source then you do not  need it ... but as the sensor has accelerometer on board then its better to use it as  booth measurement (`B,a`) are at the same reference frame. Sorry for the late response but was on holiday for a month on sea and islands without a computer :) just sails sea sand and a lot of rhum ...